# Guess the game on python 3.x Client doesnt loop

Tags: python-3.x

Server : ( or the problem is on the server ?)

```
import socket
import random

l = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


guessNumber = 0

def within(value, goal, n):
    numDifference = abs(value - goal)
    if (numDifference <= n):
        return True
    else:
        return False


randomNumber = random.randrange(0, 20)
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5000
l.bind((ip, port)) 
l.listen(5) 


while True:
    (s,ca)=l.accept()   
    print("Connection from", ca)

    while (not(within(guessNumber, randomNumber, 0))):
        guessNumber = int(s.recv(4096).decode())

        if (within(guessNumber, randomNumber, 0)):
            s.sendall("You guessed correctly!".encode())

        elif (within(guessNumber, randomNumber, 3)):
            s.sendall("You are getting close!".encode())

        else:
            s.sendall("You are way off".encode())


s.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket

gameOver = False
guessNumber = 0

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 5000))

while (gameOver != "You guessed correctly!"):

    guessNumber = input("what is your guess? ")
    s.sendall(guessNumber.encode())

    print(s.recv(4096).decode())

    gameOver = s.recv(4096).decode()

s.close()
```

If someone finds the number the game closes if you are way of or close the server sends the message but after the first guess the client wont do anything else.

Comment: You're taking twice all the data with recv (which is a blocking call). With the first call you've taken all the data so the next one waits forever.

Comment: so more recvs on client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the double recv for one:

```
print(s.recv(4096).decode())
gameOver = s.recv(4096).decode()
```

Into:

```
data = s.recv(4096).decode()
print(data)
gameOver = data
```

Comment: it works but i want some time to prosses what  i was doing wrong. Thank you

Comment: recv() is by default a blocking call. So it will endlessly wait for data. You can spexit a timeout or non blocking. Because the server only sends data once this was taken by the first recv call in the print. The second one didn't receive any data and was waiting endlessly